# Can't access to my database while installing the site

Tags: 7

When I try to install my Drupal site, I pass throughout the first 2 steps. When I type the name of database, username, and host, nothing happens. I only see the errors about username, database, and host being required.

When I looked into the error.log file, I found this error.

> XAMPP Error: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name.

Comment: That's a server misconfiguration, not a Drupal issue.

Comment: when you are testing `Drupal` why Version: 7, use latest Version: 9. Did you test with other Database? 
This is totally Xampp issue(config). Installing Drupal is Straightforward: enable opcache, Apache should be rewrite all, put port number, and this will be installed. Or you could try, Drupal officially provided - installer, which comes with built-in `Drush`

Comment: Well the thing is that I'm trying to import a drupal 7 project. I have already imported the database through xampp. When I try installing the drupal project (in xampp/htdocs), in url localhost:8080/drupal, I install ... and in the database installing phase, I give the right database, username, host... and then I get the error: required database, required username, required host. Help please.

Comment: What does the certificate say? What domain are you using? What host did you type in? Are you going through https?